# Error: 'comment' is assigned a value but never used - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, forms, var

```
var comment = [
{"name": "name", "date": "00-00-0000", "body": "comment here"}];
```

When trying to make a variable for my comments to add to my comments form on html i seem to get this ESLint error. I've been following a guide and this does the exact same thing but received no error.

I haven’t defined comment within my style or html, would this affect this at all?

Can anyone help out pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an ESLint error. It doesn't have any impact on running code whatsoever, it just warns you that you have some [code style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_style) issues in your code.

What it means is that you never seem to use that particular `comment` *assignment* within that file so it assumes that it's safe to just remove it.

Make sure you don't import that file anywhere else; from where you actually access that `comment` value. If you don't then just remove that assignment since it's unnecessary and ESLint will stop complaining.